# Select foreign key in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have table user which is in a relation ManyToMany with table activity and I wanted to select list of all activities of one user. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

i'd have this in my user entity:

```
  @ManyToMany(type => Activity, activity => activity.users)
  @JoinTable()
  public activities: Activity[];
```

and this in my activity entity:

```
  @ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.activities)
  public users: User[];
```

to select:

```
this.createQueryBuilder('user')
.leftJoinAndSelect('user.activities', 'activities')
.where('user.id = :id', { id })
.getMany();
```

assuming you have a variable id = the users id.

Comment: the join table is only supposed to be on one side of the relation. vide: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md

Comment: "We just made our relation bi-directional. Note, the inverse relation does not have a `@JoinTable`. `@JoinTable `must be only on one side of the relation." from the documentation

Comment: oh yes you're right!! my bad, thank you @Thalatta! updated answer.